# How to include/link C .lib files in a Delphi project

Tags: c, delphi, linker

We have a .lib file with functionality that must be included in a Delphi application.

It is easy to include .obj files, but for some unknown reason, this won't work for .lib files. The help is not very helpful on this. And a google search did not help that much (most helpful was to use an other linker but I would like to avoid it if possible).

One solution could be using C++ builder to create a package, but I'm not very fond of it.

So the question is, does anybody know a way to include a C .lib file into a Delphi project (so the functionality can be used)? Or is there a way to split the .lib file into .obj files.

(By the way we use 2006.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use the tlib.exe tool that comes with C++Builder. If you don't have C++Builder you can download the free C++Compiler 5.5 (http://cc.codegear.com/Free.aspx?id=24778) and use the tlib.exe from it.

Comment: Thanks, it works like a charm! Unfortunately Tlib does not recognize 64 bit lib files.

Comment: So what? Neither C++ Builder nor Delphi recognizes 64-bit code anyway.

Comment: Not yet ;-) but it is high on the list